# multiple image attachment in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, image-uploading

i am using PHPMailer class , it doesn't support multiple image upload.

```
$mailer = new phpmailer();
$mailer->IsMail();

$mailer->Subject = 'NewsLetter Request';            
$mailer->AddAddress('myemailid', 'Name');
$mailer->message_type =  "attachments";

$mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
$mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES["logo2"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["logo2"]["name"]);

$mailer->Body = $htmlBody;
$mailer->isHTML(true);
```

If i send the mail i getting the last attached image that is $_FILES['logo2'] , i am not getting the first image in the mail .

Comment: Are you using v5 of php mailer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this solution if you are using mailer v5 [Multiple attachments not going with PHPmailer v5](http://anilkonsal.com/multiple-attachments-not-going-with-phpmailer-v5)

Comment: i am using phpMailer 1.60 version